# Invalid Argument Exception Indices Not in Vectors in Word Embeddings in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, word-embedding

I am trying to run the LSTM Code and for this trying to connect the word2Vec word embeddings input, But getting error in getting the embedding look up.

Following is the code:

```
batchSize = 24
lstmUnits = 64
numClasses = 2
iterations = 100000
maxSeqLength = 250
numDimensions = 128    
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()

labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numClasses])
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batchSize, maxSeqLength])

data = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batchSize, maxSeqLength, numDimensions]),dtype=tf.float32)
# word Vector Shape = (13277, 128)
data = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(wordVectors,input_data)




saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
try:
    for i in range(iterations):
   #nextBatch shape is (24, 250)
        nextBatch, nextBatchLabels = getTrainBatch()
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={input_data: nextBatch, labels: nextBatchLabels})
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

There might be small step i'm missing. what can it be.
When i run the code, I get exception as :
[image]

Comment: First of all I think that you should fix an error in your code. You have declared two times `data`. The first occurrence should be called `wordVectors`.

Comment: the `wordVectors` is already defined, for which im using in embeddings look up with dimensions `(13277, 128)`. I can comment it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified the code that you have reported in order to let you understand how to use word embeddings in your case. In addition, you haven't specified everything (see the `optimizer` variable) so it is not possible to completely reproduce your code.

I report here a simple snippet that will allow you to get word embeddings from an input matrix of shape `(batchSize, maxSeqLength)`.

```
batchSize = 24
lstmUnits = 64
numClasses = 2
iterations = 100000
maxSeqLength = 250
numDimensions = 128
numTokens = 50

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

session = tf.InteractiveSession()
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batchSize, maxSeqLength])
# you should NOT use tf.Variable() but tf.get_variable() instead
embeddings_weights = tf.get_variable("embeddings_weights",  initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 1), shape=(numTokens, numDimensions))
input_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_weights, input_data)
result = session.run(input_embeddings, feed_dict={input_data: np.random.randint(0, numTokens, (batchSize, maxSeqLength))})
print(result.shape)
// should print (24, 250, 300)
```

If you are trying to understand why you receive that error you should debug your code and see if in the training data specified there are indexes which are not valid. In my snippet code, by using `np.random.randint()`, I forced the output elements to be in the range (0, numTokens) in order to avoid the error that you got. This happens because TensorFlow is not able to complete the lookup operation for an ID which goes out of range!